# Is there some possibility to create PIVOT with gradual subtracting of values ​in individual columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could somebody advice me, how to create PIVOT with some calculation?
Simple PIVOT with "real data" isn't problem, but I have no idea how to include some calculation even so basic like for example subtraction of values between some columns...

Please, if You'll be somebody able, try to use example of Tables and Data below...

```sql
-- Structure
-- ---------

-- Table of Products
CREATE TABLE ListProducts
(
    ProductID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(25)
);

-- Table of Processes
CREATE TABLE ListProcesses
(
    ProcessID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(25)
);

-- DataTable
CREATE TABLE Production
(
    ProductionID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ListProducts(ProductID),
    ProcessID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ListProcesses(ProcessID),
    Amount INT
);

-- Data
-- ----

INSERT INTO ListProducts(Name) VALUES ('Product1'),('Product2'),('Product3');

INSERT INTO ListProcesses(Name) VALUES ('Process1'),('Process2'),('Process3');

INSERT INTO Production(ProductID,ProcessID,Amount) VALUES
(1,1,25),(2,1,15),(3,1,20),(1,2,10),(2,2,10),(3,2,5),(1,3,5),(2,3,5);
```

I would like to get PIVOT like:

```
| Products | Process1 | Process2 | Process3 |
| Product1 |       15 |        5 |        5 |
| Product2 |        5 |        5 |        5 |
| Product3 |       15 |        5 |     NULL |
```

As You can see - output isn't like simple PIVOT but I have every 'previous' column subtracted by 'next' column (except of last column of course)...

Thank You a lot! :)

Comment: Wow... Excellent. Thank You all. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query like following using `PIVOT` and `LEAD`.

```
select [name] as Products, Process1, Process2, Process3 
from   (select t1.Name, 
               t2.amount - Isnull((Lead(t2.amount) 
                                      over(partition by T2.productid 
                                        order by t2.processid ) ), 0) amount, 
               t3.Name as ProcesName 
        from   listproducts t1 
               inner join production t2 
                       ON t1.productid = t2.productid 
               inner join listprocesses t3 
                       ON t3.processid = t2.processid) t 
       pivot ( max(amount) 
             for procesname in ([Process1], 
                                [Process2], 
                                [Process3]) ) pvt
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/CZIHJ62775)

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select lpr.name,
       sum(case when p.processid = 1 then p.amount when p.processid = 2 then -p.amount end) as process1,
       sum(case when p.processid = 2 then p.amount when p.processid = 3 then -p.amount end) as process2,
       sum(case when p.processid = 3 then p.amount end) as process3
from production p join
     listproducts lpr
     on p.productid = lpr.productid join
     listprocesses lpro
     on p.processid = lpro.processid
group by lpr.name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=978bce16273d44019b3129b43c5b36d6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Merca . . . Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can try below using lead() function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38ba9c310deb8934124542672b7b3c57)**

```
with cte as
(
select *,case when processname<>'process3' then 
amount-coalesce(lead(amount) over(partition by productname order by processname),0) else amount end as amt from 
(
select b.name as productname, c.name as processname,amount
from Production a
inner join ListProducts b on a.productid=b.ProductID
inner join ListProcesses c on a.ProcessID=c.ProcessID
)A
)

select productname, max(case when processname='Process1' then amt end) as process1,
max(case when processname='Process2' then amt end) process2,
max(case when processname='Process3' then amt end) process3
from cte 
group by productname
```

OUTPUT:

```
productname process1    process2    process3
Product1    15            5           5
Product2    5             5           5
Product3    15            5
```